# BoofCV gradle building Errors in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, boofcv

When I integrated BoofCV into Android Studio, the following error happened,

> com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
>       at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

My build.gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.huayu.boofcvandroidstart"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    //multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

compile group: 'org.boofcv', name: 'all', version: '0.20'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I handled the issue.  Include the BoofCV jars as you originally did. Then add the following to your app/build.gradle

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: "xmlpull", module: "xmlpull"
}
```

That will remove the offending xmlpull.    You also might want to include the android module, which isn't part of 'all'.

Here's an example on BoofAndroidDemo

https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/BoofAndroidDemo/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: i just wanted to thank you for this awesome library, great work!

Answer (score 0):

I have used `BoofCV` in one of my projects. You should add all the other BoofCV jars except the `XmlPullParser` because this jar conflicts with the already existing [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) present in Android.

I added BoofCV by downloading all the jars and only including the relevant ones like this:

```
dependencies {
            compile files('libs/BoofCV-android-0.19.jar')
            compile files('libs/BoofCV-calibration-0.19.jar')
            compile files('libs/BoofCV-feature-0.19.jar')
            compile files('libs/BoofCV-geo-0.19.jar')
            compile files('libs/BoofCV-io-0.19.jar')
            compile files('libs/BoofCV-ip-0.19.jar')
            compile files('libs/BoofCV-recognition-0.19.jar')
            compile files('libs/BoofCV-sfm-0.19.jar')
            compile files('libs/BoofCV-visualize-0.19.jar')
            compile files('libs/BoofCV-xuggler-0.19.jar')
            compile files('libs/core-0.26.jar')
            compile files('libs/ddogleg-0.7.jar')
            compile files('libs/georegression-0.8.jar')
            compile files('libs/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar')
            compile files('libs/xstream-1.4.7.jar')
}
```

Although this is a naive way to add the jars you could just include the relevant jars in the libs folder and add this line:

```
dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: I have removed xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar but the error still exists. Besides, I don't know why I need to add the files one by one when I can use `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: Yes you don't need to add the files one by one. I posted the single file inclusions to show you which jars i use, and they compile without any errors, so only include jars above mentioned in the libs folder and use this line: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`